# How to fix Pandas dataframe which shows NaN for string, and remove list brackets when write dataframe to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am converting python lists into Pandas dataframe, then write the dataframe into csv. The lists are as following:

```
name = ['james beard', 'james beard']
ids = [304589, 304589]
year = [1999, 1999]
co_authors = [['athman bouguettaya', 'boualem benatallah', 'lily hendra', 'kevin smith', 'mourad quzzani'], ['athman bouguettaya', 'boualem benatallah', 'lily hendra', 'kevin smith', 'mourad quzzani']]
title = ['world wide databaseintegrating the web corba and databases', 'world wide databaseintegrating the web corba and databases']
venue = ['international conference on management of data', 'international conference on management of data']

data = {
    'Name': name,
    'ID': ids,
    'Year': year,    
    'Co-author': co_authors,
    'Title:': title,
    'Venue:': venue,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','ID','Year','Co-author','Title', 'Venue'])
df
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

My questions are

(a) "Title" and "Venue" columns are shown as 'NaN' instead of their values (see below). How can I fix this?

```
Name    ID  Year    Co-author   Title   Venue
0   james beard 304589  1999    [athman bouguettaya, boualem benatallah, lily ...   NaN NaN
1   james beard 304589  1999    [athman bouguettaya, boualem benatallah, lily ...   NaN NaN
```

(b) In CSV (see below), how to add "Index" to the header and remove brackets in "Co-author"?

```
,Name,ID,Year,Co-author,Title,Venue
0,james beard,304589,1999,"['athman bouguettaya', 'boualem benatallah', 'lily hendra', 'kevin smith', 'mourad quzzani']",,
1,james beard,304589,1999,"['athman bouguettaya', 'boualem benatallah', 'lily hendra', 'kevin smith', 'mourad quzzani']",,
```

Answer (score 3):

As for first problem: in `data` you have char `:` in names `'Title:'`, `'Venue:'`
so `DataFrame` can't find `'Title'`, `'Venue'` in `data`.

You have to remove `:`

Or you can skip `columns=[...]` and it will use names with `:` -`'Title:'`, `'Venue:'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

As for second: I was searching solution with `pandas` after (or during) creating `DataFrame`.
And I didn't find it.

But if you assume you can modify data before you create `DataFrame` then you can write you version shorter

```
co_authors = [','.join(row) for row in co_authors]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah Well, I solve (b) using the below before loading into data..

```
tmp = []
for c in xrange(len(co_authors)):
    tmp.append(','.join(map(str,co_authors[c])))
co_authors = tmp
```

Comment: I don't think we want to join them by `,` when output is meant to be .csv

Comment: I was searching solution with pandas or directly in DataFrame, but I didn't found. BTW: you have strings so you don't need `map(str,...)` - `co_authors = [','.join(row) for row in co_authors]`